# getElementsByClassName vs querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript

if I use

```
var temp = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
for (var i=0, max=temp.length; i<max; i++) { 
 temp[i].className = "new_class";
}
```

everything works fine. All nodes change their classes. 
But, with gEBCN:

```
var temp = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
for (var i=0, max=temp.length; i<max; i++) { 
 temp[i].className = "new_class";
}
```

I get error. Code jumps out of the loop at some point, not finishing the job with msg "can't set className of null".
I understand that this is static vs live nodelist problem (I think), but since gEBCN is much faster and I need to traverse through huge list of nodes (tree), I would really like to use getElementsByClassName.
Is there anything I can do to stick with gEBCN and not being forced to use querySelectorAll?

Comment: Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Loop over the list *backwards*, then elements will vanish from the end (where you aren't looking any more).

```
for (var i = temp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
  temp[i].className = "new_class";
}
```

Note, however, that IE 8 supports [querySelectorAll](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) but not [getElementsByClassName](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getelementsbyclassname), so you might want to prefer querySelectorAll for better browser support.

---

Alternatively, don't remove the existing class:

```
for (var i=0, max=temp.length; i<max; i++) {  
  temp[i].className += " new_class";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Backwards loop works fine :). I will accept answer in 5 min.

Answer (score 21):

That's because `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByClassName` is live.

That means that if you add `"class"` to some element's classList, it will magically appear in `temp`.

The oposite is also true: if you remove the `"class"` class of an element inside `temp`, it will no longer be there.

Therefore, changing the classes reindexes the collection and changes its length. So the problem is that you iterate it catching its length beforehand, and without taking into account the changes of the indices.

To avoid this problem, you can:

- Use a non live collection. For example,

  ```js
  var temp = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
  ```
- Convert the live `HTMLCollection` to an array. For example, with one of these

  ```js
  temp = [].slice.call(temp);
  temp = Array.from(temp); // EcmaScript 6
  ```
- Iterate backwards. For example, see [@Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26047874/1529630).
- Take into account the changes of the indices. For example,

  ```js
  for (var i=0; i<temp.length; ++i) { 
   temp[i].className = "new_class";
   --i; // Subtract 1 each time you remove an element from the collection
  }
  ```

  ```js
  while(temp.length) { 
   temp[0].className = "new_class";
  }
  ```

Comment: (Before your edits, and still relevant to the claim that the problem is the cached `max`): That won't work. It will stop it running off the end, but it will skip elements as it goes. i.e. It will modify the first element in index `0` (causing it to be removed from the NodeList), then it will modify the *third* element which has just *moved* to index `1` (skipping the second element that moved to index `0`).

Comment: @Quentin Yea, I was getting weird results. Some of the nodes changed class, some didn't.

Comment: @Oriol I think the backward loop is the most elegant and fastest way to overcome livelist problem. I already accepted Quentin answer (he was faster). About querySelectorAll, it is much slower to work with, I have treeView with thousand nodes. gEBCN rulez.