# Using removeChild with HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, removechild, getelementsbyclassname, nodelist, htmlcollection

Consider this code:

```
xr = document.querySelectorAll('.material-tooltip'); // NodeList
console.log(xr.length); // 50
for (ya of xr)
  ya.parentNode.removeChild(ya);
zu = document.querySelectorAll('.material-tooltip');
console.log(zu.length); // 0
```

This works as expected, it removes all of the found elements. Now consider this
code:

```
xr = document.getElementsByClassName('material-tooltip'); // HTMLCollection
console.log(xr.length); // 50
for (ya of xr)
  ya.parentNode.removeChild(ya);
zu = document.getElementsByClassName('material-tooltip');
console.log(zu.length); // 25
```

It is only removing half of the found elements. What is causing this?

Comment: This helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047844/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns a non-live `NodeList`. `getElementsByClassName` returns a live `HTMLCollection`. The former behaves like any array: you go through the array, then do something for each element. But a live `HTMLCollection` is different - its contents reflect the current situation in the DOM at any time; if you remove an element from DOM, it disappears in `xr`, and if you add an element to DOM that fits the selector, it will appear in `xr`, *even after you run `getElementsByClassName`*.

Let's do the first iteration of `ya` being `0`. You remove `xr[0]`, *and it disappears from the list*. Now the element 1 is `xr[0]`; `ya` becomes `1`; and you remove `xr[1]` (element 2), with the element 1 being skipped. You then remove `xr[2]` (element 3), and skip element 4... etc.

Whenever you are operating on a live `HTMLCollection`, either go from back to front so that disappearing elements don't mess you up, or clone the `HTMLCollection` to fix its elements in place, or just do a loop removing `xr[0]` until `xr` is empty.

Comment: Shorter `while (xr[0]) xr[0].parentNode.removeChild(xr[0])`